# Office Web App deployment error on Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps, owa, sharepoint-server

I am using windows server 2012-R2 and which was having Office web apps configured previously. Due to some technical error server crashed and i re-installed it as per MSDN article. 
Note:- when i run New-OfficeWebAppsFarm command **first time** after server rebuild i get the error **"Office web apps server has encountered an unrecoverable failure"**  , but this error is only one time , if i run the same **command again** with all properties second time, my Office web app deployment was successful and I can see the response correctly. 
But the problem is , when i try to set this server as OWA server from my SharePoint server getting the error as below.

```
New-SPWOPIBinding : Sorry, we have encountered an error and New-SPWOPIBinding
has failed.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName "servername.com" -AllowHTTP:$true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Share...tNewWOPIBinding
   :SPCmdletNewWOPIBinding) [New-SPWOPIBinding], SPCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewWOPIB
```

Response after running **New-OfficeWebAppsFarm** command second time

[image: Response after running New-OfficeWebAppsFarm]

When i try to check the deployement status again with command **Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm** getting this error.

[image: get command error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue,
There was an error in the web config file,

```
 <identity impersonate="true" />
```

was there and i changed it to

`<trust level="Full" />`

```
<system.web>                          <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />             <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>                           </system.web>
```